# Stable Partition shell program output

Tags: bash, shell

I have a big directory that I'm trying to navigate. I am looking for file names that match a certain pattern. For this, i use the find command.

There is also a subset of the filenames that match my pattern that contain a substring that i am interested in. I would like for those files to be printed first, while also having all the output ordered alphabetically (as if the values were partitioned and then the two partitions sorted separately or as if the output was sorted, then stably partitioned).

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

So far I have only tried sorting the output, and grepping through it to filter out the file names that contain the substring I'm searching for. Not having to do that would be better though (The directory is pretty large and searching twice is kinda slow).

```
find . <...more stuff comes here...> | sort | grep <substring>
find . <...more stuff comes here...> | sort | grep -v <substring>
```

I have also though of doing the following:

```
find . <...more stuff comes here...> | sort > tempfile
tempfile > grep <substring>
tempfile >  grep -v <substring>
rm tempfile
```

This is faster, but this way I still have to grep through the list twice, and do extra file IO in between, which feels wasteful.

(By the way, I am not allowed to show the pattern or the substring.)

In short: I want to see partitioned results instead of having to filter twice.

EDIT: an example would be:
with this output of the `find | sort` commands:

```
./aaaaaafoo
./bbbbbbfoo
./ccccccbar
./ddddddbar
./eeeeeefoo
./ffffffbaz
./ggggggfoobar
./hhhhhhbar
```

With substring `'foo'`, i want the output to be:

```
./aaaaaafoo
./bbbbbbfoo
./eeeeeefoo
./ggggggfoobar
./ccccccbar
./ddddddbar
./ffffffbaz
./hhhhhhbar
```

Comment: Your tempfile method is likely to be fairly optimal. grep is very efficient. While you could use awk  or perl or somesuch to print matches/nonmatches simultaneously, it will probably run more slowly.

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126209/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-based-on-the-content-into-multiple-text-files - but all the methods suggested seem to run significantly slower than two greps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method will depend on where your bottlenecks are (probably the speed of your I/O) so you will need to benchmark any suggested methods against your actual data. To give you an idea, I ran a simple test on a 2GB word file, reading and writing to nvme storage:

```
$ time ( grep 'ab*ad' <words2 >a1; grep -v 'ab*ad' <words2 >a2 )

real    0m12.226s
user    0m9.733s
sys 0m1.784s

$  time awk <words2 '(/ab*ad/){print >"a1";next}{print}'>a2

real    0m35.864s
user    0m33.473s
sys 0m1.680s

$ time perl -ne '/ab*ad/ ? print STDOUT : print STDERR' <words2 >a1 2>a2

real    4m40.959s
user    1m8.288s
sys 3m32.057s

$ time ( while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ ab*ad ]] && echo "$line" || echo 1>&2 "$line"; done ) <words2 >a1 2>a2
^C # aborted the run as it was so slow
```

The two grep method, which we might guess to be inefficient, turns out to really not be. If I/O might be a bottleneck, perhaps a tweak will help:

```
find . <...more stuff comes here...> | sort | gzip -1c >tempfile
zcat tempfile | grep <substring>
zcat tempfile | grep -v <substring>
rm tempfile`
```

This isn't helpful in my configuration:

```
$time ( gzip -1c <words2 >wz; zcat wz |\
        fgrep 'abad' >a1; zcat wz | fgrep -v 'abad' >a2 )

real    0m59.072s
user    1m6.804s
sys 0m3.609s

$ ls -la words2 wz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jhnc jhnc 1989791744 Feb  8 23:40 words2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jhnc jhnc  661174851 Feb  9 00:11 wz
```

but notice that the datafile is one third the size which may be advantageous with slow storage.

A final note: I suspect the sort will be the slowest part of the procedure if you have a large datafile.

Comment: Please test with the same machine: `find | sort | tee >( grep -v substring >b.txt) | grep substring >a.txt`

Comment: I haven't been doing `find|sort` but parallel ought to be faster - although it seems not by much: ~10s real 3s user

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
rm -f a.txt # needed because of >> operator
find . <...more stuff comes here...> | sort | 
    awk ' /substring/ { print >>"a.txt"; next } {print}' >b.txt
```

Note 1: `/substring/` is a regular expression

Note 2: You can also redirect to e.g. `/dev/fd/5` or use `print | "command ....` inside awk. See `man awk` .

Comment: On a 2GB wordfile with a simple regexp, awk runs about 5 times more slowly than 2 greps for me.

Comment: ok. I have never tested it. Alternative solution: Write a C program.

Comment: Actually, I'm using nvme storage. If the tempfile is on an hdd, reading twice could well be the bigger bottleneck. It's going to depend on the size of the tempfile and the speed of I/O.

Comment: That's neat! But, after hearing about the performance, I'd rather stick to my 2 greps. I was hoping I wouldn't have to write any C++ but using STL it should be easy enough. Thanks a lot though! I feel like i should accept an answer, so if you include that observation on your answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Another solution, that needs only 1 `find .. | sort |`part: `find | sort |  tee >( grep -v substring >b.txt) | grep substring >a.txt`